# how to add stable/nfs-server-provisioner chart with helm version 3

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I want to add stable/nfs-server-provisioner chart with helm version 3. Already went through various online literatures about this, but all of them talking with respect to helm version 2.
However, my requirement is with version 3.

my helm version

```
/home/ravi>helm version
version.BuildInfo{Version:"v3.5.4", GitCommit:"1b5edb69df3d3a08df77c9902dc17af864ff05d1", GitTreeState:"clean", GoVersion:"go1.15.11"}
/home/ravi>
```

error seen with helm 3

```
/home/ravi>helm install nfs-release-1  stable/nfs-server-provisioner --namespace ricinfra 
Error: failed to download "stable/nfs-server-provisioner" (hint: running `helm repo update` may help)
/home/ravi>
```

Somewhere I found to add helm stable repo as below. however failed.

```
/home/ravi>helm repo add stable https://kubernetes-charts.storage.googleapis.com
Error: repo "https://kubernetes-charts.storage.googleapis.com" is no longer available; try "https://charts.helm.sh/stable" instead
/home/ravi>
```

then added new repo

```
/home/ravi>helm repo add stable https://charts.helm.sh/stable
"stable" has been added to your repositories
/home/ravi>helm repo list
NAME    URL                          
local   http://127.0.0.1:8879/charts 
stable  https://charts.helm.sh/stable
/home/ravi>
```

But still unsuccessful to add the provisioner.

```
/home/ravi>helm install nfs-release-1  stable/nfs-server-provisioner --namespace ricinfra
WARNING: This chart is deprecated
Error: Kubernetes cluster unreachable: error loading config file "/root/.kube/config": open /root/.kube/config: permission denied
/home/ravi>

/home/ravi>helm repo update
Hang tight while we grab the latest from your chart repositories...
...Unable to get an update from the "local" chart repository (http://127.0.0.1:8879/charts):
    Get "http://127.0.0.1:8879/charts/index.yaml": dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8879: connect: connection refused
...Successfully got an update from the "stable" chart repository
Update Complete. ⎈Happy Helming!⎈
/home/ravi>
```

Any idea how to fix this?

thanks.

Comment: Your [newer question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75703008/what-is-helm-stable-and-incubator-repository) asks something similar; are these basically the same?  You might be looking for the [nfs-subdir-external-provisioner installation instructions](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/nfs-subdir-external-provisioner#with-helm).

Comment: thanks i got similar solution like https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/nfs-ganesha-server-and-external-provisioner/blob/5225a85c242e025f73bd03b832fd0bbd3bdb3b20/charts/nfs-server-provisioner/README.md

Answer (score 0):

I'm actively using kubernetes-sigs-nfs with Helm 3.

**Link:** https://kubernetes-sigs.github.io/nfs-subdir-external-provisioner/

To add Helm repo:

```
helm repo add nfs-subdir-external-provisioner https://kubernetes-sigs.github.io/nfs-subdir-external-provisioner
```

You should have NFS mount before running the storage class. After creating your NFS mount:

```
helm install nfs-subdir-external-provisioner \
nfs-subdir-external-provisioner/nfs-subdir-external-provisioner \
--set nfs.server=<NFSServerIP> \
--set nfs.path=<NFSPath, e.g /mnt/nfs> \
--set storageClass.onDelete=true
```