# what is helm stable and incubator repository

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I search online but could not get what is stable and incubator helm chart repositories ? Why are the two used? [stable and incubator repo](https://helm.sh/blog/new-location-stable-incubator-charts/)

I see nfs server chart is deprecated in stable repo. any workaround to get this chart?

```
/home/ravi>helm search repo stable | grep nfs
    stable/nfs-client-provisioner           1.2.11          3.1.0                   DEPRECATED - nfs-client is an automatic provisi...
    stable/nfs-server-provisioner           1.1.3           2.3.0                   DEPRECATED - nfs-server-provisioner is an out-o...    
/home/ravi>
```

Answer (score 0):

The Helm project formerly maintained a set of standard charts that packaged a number of popular open-source application.  These charts are no longer maintained, and if you see a reference to the `stable` (or `incubator`) repositories, you should contact the source that produced the charts.

Those charts do have a [GitHub repository](https://github.com/helm/charts) which prominently notes:

> **This project is no longer supported.**
>
> **Nov 13, 2020** [...] support for this project will formally end, at which point the stable and incubator chart repos will be marked obsolete. At that time these chart repos will likely be garbage collected and no longer available. This git repository will remain as an archive.

The charts do technically still exist and you can technically use them, but they're not supported or maintained any more.

When these charts were supported, generally the `stable` charts worked well.  The `incubator` charts frequently worked, but did not necessarily follow Helm or Kubernetes best practices in their setup.  Often a vendor chart was preferable to an "official" `incubator` chart.

For `nfs-client-provisioner` in particular, you can find the former [chart directory](https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/nfs-client-provisioner) in GitHub, which has a [stale link to an old Kubernetes project](https://github.com/kubernetes-retired/external-storage/tree/master/nfs-client), which in turn links to [kubernetes-sigs/nfs-subdir-external-provisioner](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/nfs-subdir-external-provisioner).  That includes [installation instructions](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/nfs-subdir-external-provisioner#with-helm) that don't rely on the discontinued repository.